# Dual norm of integral vector norm

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, lebesgue-measure, inner-products, dual-spaces

For $x\in\mathbb{C}^n$, consider the following norm:

$\|x\|_{B} := \int_{B}|\langle x,y\rangle| \ d\mu(y),$

where $B:=\{y\in\mathbb{C}^n \ | \ \|y\|_2 \leq 1\}$ is the euclidean-norm ($\|\circ\|_2$) unit ball.

**My question is:** what is the dual norm of $\|\circ\|_{B}$?

In other words, is there a ''nice'' (alternative) closed form expression for

$\|z\|_{B}^* = \sup_{\{x \ | \ \|x\|_{B}\leq 1\}}\langle z,x\rangle$
?

I understand that this is a vague question since ''nice'' is subjective and the expression above is technically a closed form expression. However, any alternative expression or intuition on how to derive an equivalent expression would be much appreciated. Any related definitions in the literature would also help.

Comment: Is $\mu$ the Lebesgue measure?

Comment: What is $\mu?$ If for instance $\mu$ is concentrated on the hyperplane $ h^\perp$ then $\|h\|_B=0$ and you have not defined a norm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure. By substitution it is clear that,

$$\left\|x\right\|_B = \left\|x\right\|_2\int_{y\in B} \left|y_n\right| \mathrm d y$$ and this proves that, $$\left\|z\right\|_B^* = \frac1{\displaystyle \int_{y\in B} \left|y_n\right| \mathrm d y} \left\|z\right\|_2$$

Comment: Thanks! So if I understand correctly, this can be shown as follows: let $Q$ be a unitary matrix such that $Qx = e_n\|x\|_2$ (the n-th canonical basis vector). Then $\int_B|\langle x,y\rangle |d\mu(y) = \int_B|\langle Q^TQx,y\rangle |d\mu(y) = \int_B|\langle Qx,Qy\rangle |d\mu(y) = \int_B|\langle Qx,y\rangle |d\mu(y) = \|x\|_2\int_B|\langle e_n,y\rangle |d\mu(y) = \|x\|_2\int_B|y_n |d\mu(y).$

Comment: Exactly and you can compute the integral easily. I think there is a closed form formula for it.

Comment: I am not sure about the steps but the idea is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If $\mu$ is invariant by the orthogonal group, then $\|x\|_B$ is proportional to the Euclidean norm,and up to a multiplicative constant the norm is self dual.

Comment: Thanks! I did mean for $\mu$ to be the Lebesgue measure. (Up to a constant) Is this a well known characterization of the Euclidean norm?

Comment: This is a subtle question, since the dual norm is on the dual space, which is different from the initial space $E$ . If you decide to identify them by a bilinear form on $E$ which is a Euclidean scalar product, the answer to your question is yes.